# Cant figure the correct config of my .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have been trying without luck to configure my .htaccess to work properly but I can't manage to make it work. It is quite simple but yet its not working. It is in a Wordpress enviroment and I want it to:

- Redirect whole old domain to new domain
- Redirect specific pages of old domain to specific pages in new domain
- I want the redirects to exclude a certain folder in the old domain

I came up with the following code:

```
RewriteEngine on
Redirect 301 /sistema-gestion-erp-empresa/ http://marques-ps.com/soluciones/microsoft-dynamics-nav-navision/
Redirect 301 /sistema-gestion-erp-empresa/ http://marques-ps.com/soluciones/microsoft-dynamics-nav-navision/
Redirect 301 /sistema-gestion-erp-empresa/ http://marques-ps.com/soluciones/microsoft-dynamics-nav-navision/
Redirect 301 /sistema-gestion-erp-empresa/ http://marques-ps.com/soluciones/microsoft-dynamics-nav-navision/
Redirect 301 /sistema-gestion-erp-empresa/ http://marques-ps.com/soluciones/microsoft-dynamics-nav-navision/
Redirect 301 /sectores-tic-erp-empresas/sistema-gestion-erp-distribucion-alimentacion-ekon/ http://marques-ps.com/soluciones/unit4-ekon/
Redirect 301 /sectores-tic-erp-empresas/sistema-gestion-erp-distribucion-alimentacion-ekon/ http://marques-ps.com/soluciones/unit4-ekon/
Redirect 301 /soluciones-tic/sistema-crm-gestion-servicio-clientes-ekon/ http://marques-ps.com/soluciones/unit4-ekon/
Redirect 301 /soluciones-tic/sistema-crm-gestion-servicio-clientes-ekon/ http://marques-ps.com/soluciones/unit4-ekon/
Redirect 301 /soluciones-tic/sistema-crm-gestion-servicio-clientes-ekon/ http://marques-ps.com/soluciones/unit4-ekon/
Redirect 301 /sectores-tic-erp-empresas/sistema-gestion-erp-agroalimentario-hortofruticola-cooperativas-agricolas-ekon-agro/ http://marques-ps.com/soluciones/unit4-ekon/
Redirect 301 /sistema-gestion-erp-ekon-empresas/ http://marques-ps.com/soluciones/unit4-ekon/
Redirect 301 /sistema-gestion-erp-ekon-empresas/ http://marques-ps.com/soluciones/unit4-ekon/
Redirect 301 /servicios-tic/especialistas-desarrollos-soluciones-sistemas-gestion-erp-ekon/ http://marques-ps.com/soluciones/unit4-ekon/
Redirect 301 /programa-sistema-gestion-erp-pyme-ekon/ http://marques-ps.com/soluciones/unit4-ekon/
Redirect 301 /servicios-tic/nube-cloud-computing-empresas/ http://marques-ps.com/consultoria/cloud-y-virtualizacion/
Redirect 301 /servicios-tic/ http://marques-ps.com/consultoria/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/intranet
RewriteRule (.*) http://marques-ps.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

For some reason the specific 301's are not working and they still result in a 404 Error in the new page. Btw, the old domain is http://marques-tic.com.

Any help would be VERY much appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Paco.

Comment: working in wordpress??

Comment: Try out without the `/` at the beginning like `Redirect 301 sistema-gestion-erp-empresa/ http://marques-ps.com/soluciones/microsoft-dynamics-nav-navision/`

Comment: Yes, Wordpress (old installation) The new one has the default WP htaccess.

Comment: @vard your approach didnt work. I still get a 404 in the new site.

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1: Htaccess file redirect**

Redirect rule place in .htaccess for and change paramlinks.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain\.com$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.olddomain\.com$
  RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

**Case 2 : Plugins make things easy,**

Redirection is a WordPress plugin to manage 301 redirections and keep track of 404 errors without requiring knowledge of Apache .htaccess files.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/

Comment: Hi! The problem is I want to point certain pages to certain others in the new site. In fact, I want to end up deleting the old website install and make its results disappear from Google in the long term. There are currently 17 pages getting clicks in Google SERP from the old domain, and that is what I want to fix.